# Get list of property names and values for a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab

In the MATLAB documentation for a particular type of plot (i.e. trisurf), it shows how to add properties, but does not give a list of what properties are applicable.  Is there a way to find which properties and values are available for a particular plot type?

Comment: Is `get(gcf)` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Alejandro: That will give a list of figure properties, not properties for a plot object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h = trisurf(...);

get(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition try [Property Inspector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inspect.html): `inspect(h)`.

Notice, if you plot multiple lines with plot you will get handle for each line. To open the inspector you will have to pass individual handle.

```
h = plot(magic(5));
inspect(h(1))
```

There is also a great alternative to `inspect` - [UIINSPECT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methodspropertiescallbacks-of-an-object). Download it from the File Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[@Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955657/get-list-of-property-names-and-values-for-a-matlab-plot/3955671#3955671) and [@yuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955657/get-list-of-property-names-and-values-for-a-matlab-plot/3955683#3955683) have made good suggestions as to how you can access the properties for a given plot handle.

If you also want to know what these properties actually do, you should look at the help. Normally, like for [plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html), there is a direct link to the full list of properties available with explanation. Surprisingly, this is not the case for [trisurf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trisurf.html), as you mentioned. However, the documentation does indicate that `trisurf` creates a [patch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) object. This means that `trisurf` has all the [patch properties that you can find explained here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html).